# C# - Como abrir o Form2 sem perder as informações da TextBox que está no Form1 e vice versa?

Tags: c#

```
namespace TesteAbertura
{
    public partial class FormularioTeste : Form
    {
        public FormularioTeste()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            panel1.Controls.Clear();
            Form1 f = new Form1();          
            f.TopLevel = false;
            panel1.Controls.Add(f);
            f.Show();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.TopLevel = false;
            panel1.Controls.Add(f);
            f.Show();

        }
```

Comment: Não entendi ...?

Comment: Em cada um dos formulários tem uma caixa de texto que digito algo, quando clico no botão para mudar para o Form2 o que foi digitado na caixa de texto do Form1 desaparece, eu quero que permaneça o que foi digitado nas caixas de texto de ambos formulários.

Comment: Não é só tirar  esse `panel1.Controls.Clear()`?

Comment: Linq tirar panel1.Controls.Clear() não resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao chamar:

```
Form1 f = new Form1();
```

Você está criando um novo objeto do tipo Form1, se toda vez que clica no botão, cria um novo, ele com certeza perderá a informação no textbox.

Você pode colocar a definição dos forms no form principal, e mostrá-los quando for necessário, assim reterá a informação nos controles:

```cs
namespace TesteAbertura
{
    public partial class FormularioTeste : Form
    {
        // Definição no escopo da classe
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(); 

        public FormularioTeste()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
            f1.TopLevel = false;
            panel1.Controls.Add(f1);
            f1.Show();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
            f2.TopLevel = false;
            panel1.Controls.Add(f2);
            f2.Show();
        }
}
```

Porém, se você fechar o Form, o GC vai coletá-lo mesmo assim (o form será descartado), será necessário cancelar o evento de fechamento:

```cs
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();
}
```

Normalmente não se usa Form dentro de um Panel, Forms são abstrações de janelas, mas nada te impede (fiquei abismado que isso funciona), o mais adequado para seu caso é utilizar UserControl ou até mesmo dois paineis alternando sua visibilidade.

Comment: Edney muito obrigado por solucionar esse meu problema, funcionou perfeitamente, agora as informações não desaparecem mais. Como disse mais acima para o David Pereira eu sou novato na programação e busco sempre aprender e tentar compreender a linguagem C#. Que você e a todos que tentaram solucionar esse problema tenham uma ótima semana.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma variável e receber esses dados no formulário 2, e quando voltar você preenche novamente.

Por exemplo :

public Form2(string texto)
{
//.......
}

E quando voltar para o outro form você devolve o que estava escrito.

Comment: David Pereira obrigado pela sua resposta, quero lhe dizer que sou novato na programação e estudo por hobby, peço por gentileza poderia deixar a sua resposta ainda mais clara para que eu possa compreender melhor e conseguir incluir o seu exemplo no código.